# A separate build configuration in make

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile to build my project:

```
CFLAGS := -g -O2 -MD -MP
SRCDIR := src
OBJDIR := build
BINDIR := bin

SRC := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJ := $(SRC:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJ:%.o=%.d)

all: $(BINDIR)/main

$(BINDIR)/main: $(OBJ) | $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(OBJ): $(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean distclean
clean: 
    rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
distclean: clean
    rm -rf $(BINDIR)

$(OBJDIR) $(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

-include $(DEPS)
```

I plan from time to tim check to my program for memory leaks using valgrind. But then it is advised not to use any compiler optimization at all.

If I simply added a target `valgrind` with modified `CFLAGS`, the project won't get completely rebuilt. 
On the other hand, after a valgrind check, I'll have to make a distclean, because everything will be unoptimzed.

This doesn't sound well. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: Use separate `OBJDIR` and `BINDIR` values for the two cases (and check using `ifeq`, etc. against `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`) or look into supporting checking/storing compilation flags as part of the prerequisites of a target (solutions are out there but they are complex).

Comment: @EtanReisner 
 
And what if someone calls `make all valgrind`?

Comment: Erroring out is the only real solution there unless you keep two sets of variables for the binaries, object files, etc. and use the fact that make target-specific variables are inherited by prerequisites to set them correctly for the appropriate prerequisite targets (and keep the actual building rules generic). You can absolutely do that if you wanted though.